# Is it possible to create an iOS app that can encode video from the camera in a format playable on android?

Tags: android, ios, video, video-encoding

Similarly put,

I'm curious if an app like SnapChat is able to record video and encode it in a standard format, that is then playable inside SnapChat (possibly on a different device type), so that they don't have to do server side transcoding of video for different platforms (Android, iOS, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is totally possible. Both platforms will encode and play AVC+AAC in an MP4 container.

Comment: Is there any reason why the creator of a multi-platform video sharing mobile app would not do this? Would doing so while recording be prohibitively resource intensive or anything like that? Or is this more or less a slam dunk solution to cross device compatibility? Cheers!

Comment: If you record in the best possible quality on a device, it may not be playable on older devices. For example, an iPhone 6 can record 1080p in High profile (i think), but an iPhone 4 can only playback 720p Main profile. To be safe you can always record at something like 640x480 Baseline@3.1 But this will produce a lower fidelity image at a higher bitrate.

Answer (score 1):

I can remember that a while ago we wanted to do something like this and it wasn't possible.

It could be possible that iOS changed but I doubt it.

We end up using zencoder. Quite easy to implement and not expensive at all.

Good luck.